# MongoDB error message is not JSON friendly

Tags: json, mongodb, error-handling

I am building an application using the MEAN stack and I have set up my server to return any error messages to the app in JSON format to be displayed for the user.

My issue comes with certain MongoDB errors that contain both single quotes and double quotes breaking the JSON when it is to be parsed in the browser. Is there any solutions to work around this?

MongoDB error message:

```
'not authorized on database to execute command { insert: "posts", documents: [   { title: "My First Post", author: "Me", content: "Blah blah blah, here is the content.", status: "published", permalink: "my-first-post", post_date: new Date(1335205543511), _id: ObjectId(\'58812868542aae2d0c6d6917\'), create_date: new Date(1484859496493), __v: 0 } ], ordered: false, writeConcern: { w: 1 } }'
```